# Missing Hibernate Attribute (due to inheritance?)

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, inheritance

I have an SQL table that has been mapped in Hibernate. I have been receiving the following error:

**java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unable to locate Attribute  with the the given name [memId] on this ManagedType**

What's got me so confused (and why my issue differed from any other questions I could find), is that I don't *want* to have a memId attribute. There is no field called memId in my class. The only reason (that I can think of) that Hibernate would be expecting such an Attribute is that the mapped class extends an interface which contains declarations for getMemId() and setMemId() methods.

Is that enough for Hibernate to assume there is an attribute called memId? Or are there any other possible reasons as to why a model without a field named memId would expect such an Attribute?

Comment: Probably, try setting @Transient on that property

Comment: Mmmm, I meant to try that but I accidentally put @Transactional... hold on

Comment: EDIT: Putting @ Transient on the getter and setter in the class did not work. If by property you meant the field, it doesn't exist! This is very baffling to me.

Comment: Just put it on getter, not setter, also when you do, tell me do you get the same error?

Comment: Yes, same error.

Comment: Can you update your question and give us the code of interface and your class, also update the error since it's missing name of the `Bean` at the end